# App keeps crashing when attempting to add a row?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I keep getting this:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 sections after the update'

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class UtilityBillTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var bills = [UtilityBill]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }

    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }

    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToBillList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
        if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? UtilitiesViewController, let bill = sourceViewController.bill {
            // Add a new meal item.

            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: bills.count, section: 0)
            bills.append(bill)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .bottom)               
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` return variables that reflect values that correspond to your data. It doesn't make sense to have them hardcoded at `0`. The error says you've inserted data into the first section (section 0), but you still have 0 sections, which doesn't make sense. Surely you want at least 1 section.

Try these implementations:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return bills.count
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked now I'm just trying to implement the tableView with the reusableCell. That my next task